# VBA last row command

Tags: vba, excel

I am creating a VLOOKUP in VBA and it works fine but I am not able to define as "range" only the cells in column A that contain a value. 
The below line takes into account all column A and its giving me error messages for all the empty cells in the column. Any idea how can I fix the syntax?

```
   Set lookFor = book1.Sheets(1).Range("A3" & LastRow)
```

Comment: perhaps instead of re-creating VLOOKUP you should either use 1) `Application.WorksheetFunction.Vlookup()` or 2) use [`Find()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-find-method-excel) instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use SpecialCells to locate text and number constants.

```
Set lookFor = book1.Sheets(1).Range("A1:A" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumbers+xlTextValues)
```